# Angular 2 Material: Define custom breakpoints

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm searching the way to define custom breakpoints, I use Angular 2 Material, Angular 4 and Angular CLI. Need to say, that I'm totally new to all of this. I already saw this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0EXenG?p=preview) and have tried to integrate it to my app, but it seems not working (I'm stuck with importing `config.js` to my `index.html`):

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="../../config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>
```

In Webstorm it looks like this:

[image]

But `config.js` was imported with no problems, my IDE doesn't show any errors. Here is `config.js`:

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    // Copy of compiler options in standard tsconfig.json
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  meta: {
    'typescript': {
      "exports": "ts"
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {

    'app': './src',

    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/flex-layout' : 'npm:@angular/flex-layout/bundles/flex-layout.umd.js',

    // other libraries
    'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.0.10/lib/typescript.js',
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './boot.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Does anyone know, why can't I call `System.import('app').catch(console.error.bind(console));` in my `index.html`?

Or if you have the full working solution for integrating custom breakpoints to Angular 4 application, please, share it.

Comment: my IDE doesn't show any errors and the IDE is ...

Comment: I also get this error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined"